# Detect touch slide on element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've build myself a navigation drawer for my website. The problem is that I want to detect, if the user moves the navigation drawer with the finger to the right (with a slide). If this slide events get's triggered, I want to click a hidden close button.

I've searched a lot but I can't find an event that sounds right. So how can I do this?

```js
jQuery("nav").on("slide-right", function({
  jQuery(".close").click();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%
  background: #666;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="close"></div>
```

Comment: [jQuery mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/) may be more adapted than jQuery for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jQuery mobile is a way to heavy for me (because I only needed swipe events) I've found this little plugin:

https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/Tocca.js

This is how I implemented the touch event:

```
jQuery(".mobile_nav").on('swiperight',function(){
    jQuery(".mobile_menu_bar_toggle").click();
});
```

This clicks the close button of my navigation and closes it when the user swipes right on my navigation.

Comment: I was looking for a lightweight thumb slider and while that's the lightest I've seen so far it's still 8kb so way too heavy for what it offers. Seems like I'll have to make my own :/